# C++ Adding property to struct generates "triggered a breakpoint"

Tags: c++, visual-studio

I am developing an application for reading and editing Exif metadata in a JPEG file using Visual Studio 2013 on Windows 8.1.

I have a class called Photoprove and I am using a demo.cpp file to check the functionality of this class.

Inside the Photoprove class I have a struct called Metadata  to hold various values for an Exif field inside the JPEG, it starts like this:

```
struct Metadata{
    int tagID=0;
    BYTE* values;
    int noValues=0;
    long valuesStart=0;
    int ifdNo = 0;  //0=IFD0, 1=Exif, 2=GPS, 3=Interop, 4=IFD1
    ...
```

At the moment, everything is working fine but I want to add another property to show the tagID  in hex so I modify the struct to:

```
struct Metadata{
    int tagID=0;
    std::string tagHex = "";
    BYTE* values;
    ....
```

That is the only change but causes a "triggered a breakpoint" error at the very end of main() in demo.cpp - it happens at the closing bracket.

Here is the contents of the dbgheap.c at the point where it stops which again, is the closing bracket.

```
 extern "C" CRTIMP int __cdecl _CrtIsValidHeapPointer(const void * pUserData )
 {
    if (!pUserData)
        return FALSE;

    if (!_CrtIsValidPointer(pHdr(pUserData), sizeof(_CrtMemBlockHeader),   FALSE))
        return FALSE;

    return HeapValidate( _crtheap, 0, pHdr(pUserData) );
 }
```

I'd appreciate suggestions on what might be causing this to happen.

Comment: When the "crash" happens, go *up* the call stack until you reach your code, and look there instead of the CRT code that raise the exception.

Comment: Regarding the cause for the crash, how do you *use* the structure? Do you use any operation not compatible with objects or `std::string ? Like e.g. `memcpy` or similar? Can you please try  to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). and show us?

Comment: Is your structure defined in a header file? If so, it's best to do a complete rebuild of everything. Can you redo your tests, but rebuilding everything each time?

Comment: I'm going to try a complete rebuild as suggested by @Aaron McDaid  as there are some other parts of my code that need tidying up. I'll let you know how I get on

Comment: By "rebuild" I do not mean to delete your code and rewrite it all! I simply mean find the relevant option in Visual Studio to force a recompilation of all objects

Comment: I figured that was what you meant @Aaron McDaid but I'd already tried that so decided to take it a bit further than you meant, I've found in the past that unless there is a very clear indication of where the problem lies (which is what I had hoped for here),  reworking a project from scratch can be faster than trying to track down a runtime error and ending up creating new errors. The application isn't very big but it's fairly complex involving a number of pointers to arrays and I suspect that I am running into memory collisions.